# If I change my computers date / time, what could be affected?

Tags: windows, date-time

I have recently come across a couple of games that trigger certain events only at certain times and/or dates  (Superbrothers Sword & Sworcery, and FEZ).

If I want for such events to happen, I would have to wait for that times, but obviously, I could simply change my systems time to make the game "think" it is already such time.

My question is, how could that affect the regular behavior of my computer? Would changing times and dates affect something important, like maybe some non-user scheduled tasks, or keeping files synced or something?

What could be the "worst case" consequences of doing it?

I know that for instance, most backup programs know that in certain cases, files may have a difference of exactly one hour, for the cases of Daylight saving time changes, and they ignore such differences (if the files are the same size, etc). But what about other programs, and with differences of not only an hour, but several, and maybe even complete days?

So, in general, is it a bad idea to change my systems time, and I should just wait for the "real" time to happen? Or is it relatively "safe" to do it and then simply change it back when done?

I have also tried a program called "RunAsDate" that supposedly tells the application you choose to run on a specific date and time, but it didn't work (the games executables never run, but I haven't tried with other .exe's). Are there other programs capable of that?

Additional info: I am using Windows 8 pro, as for hardware specs I guess they are irrelevant.

Thanks.

Comment: How can this be considered not constructive!? It is a perfectly possible scenario, and even not for my specific case, sometimes you NEED to change the system date (e.g. your motherboards BIOS battery ran out and can't keep track of time any more).

Answer (score 2):

It can wreak havoc with certain security certificates, screw up VPN link connections, cause some website admin sessions to fail, and I've seen future date settings blow away antivirus package updates and put them into a failure mode that can only be fixed by complete removal and install. Otherwise it can be done.

Comment: And also changing your local time may not do anything at all to your access to the game as when the game is started, it will check back to the server and use the Server time, not your local time.

Comment: And since most games that fall in the MMO category require a connection to a server somewhere, that's pretty much what drives what is available. The only control you might have is if the event is time-zone based, in which case, you change your reported time zone only.

Comment: @Darius this is not the case, since the games actually encourage you to change the time (one of them actually has an achievement for doing so).